# Display MySQL Query results in Rails App

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Good Day,

Im Looking for some assistance displaying the output of a query result from my MySQL table in the Rails APP.

The DB and Rails are linked and I can Display the full table without issues. How can i Display the following Query results?

Below is the MySQL Query

```
SELECT
timetable.subject,
timetable.paper
FROM
timetable
WHERE
timetable.`start` < NOW() AND
timetable.`stop` > NOW()
ORDER BY
timetable.`id` ASC
```

Not Sure if i need to save the query in MySQL and call it from Rails. Or can i acheive this using rails code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Timetable.where("start < ? AND stop > ?", Time.now, Time.now).order('id ASC').pluck(:subject, :paper)
```

Comment: Doesnt Work on my side with trying that in the html file, Sorry my MySQL and RAILS knowledge is very limited as i'm just beginning, To Display the output in a table for instance, would it look like this  <table>
  <tbody>
   <% @Timetables.each do |timetable| %>
     <tr>
      <td><% Timetable.where("start < ? AND stop > ?", Time.now, Time.now).order('id ASC').pluck(:subject, :paper) %></td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

Comment: First you need a `Timetable` model. Then in the controller you use the above query to create a `@timetables` object. Then in the view you do `<table><tbody><% @timetables.each do |timetable| %><tr><td><%= timetable[0] %></td><td>%= timetable[1] %></td></tr><% end %></tbody></table>`

Comment: So if im correct. With a existing scaffold already generated for that DB, I Would create the object adding the above code into the existing controller?  And then Call the object in the html view?

Comment: Exactly. You could technically use this code in the view and iterate over the results but you don't want to put complex logic in view.

Comment: Thanks, I did Manage to create the object in the existing Controller and link to it in another html view.. Appreciate your help